# sbt: How do I resolve Maven dependencies that uses Maven properties

Tags: scala, maven, sbt

For example:

```scala
lazy val someProject = project
  .settings(
    scalaVersion := "2.12.3",
    libraryDependencies += "org.jcuda" % "jcuda" % "0.8.0"
  )
```

The above does not resolve:

```
sbt:someProject> update
[info] Updating ...
[info] downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jcuda/jcuda/0.8.0/jcuda-0.8.0.jar ...
[warn]  Detected merged artifact: [NOT FOUND  ] org.jcuda#jcuda-natives;0.8.0!jcuda-natives.jar (16ms).
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn]   https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/jcuda/jcuda-natives/0.8.0/jcuda-natives-0.8.0-${jcuda.os}-${jcuda.arch}.jar
[info]  [SUCCESSFUL ] org.jcuda#jcuda;0.8.0!jcuda.jar (227ms)
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::              FAILED DOWNLOADS            ::
[warn]  :: ^ see resolution messages for details  ^ ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: org.jcuda#jcuda-natives;0.8.0!jcuda-natives.jar
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
```

Note the `${jcuda.os}` appearing in the error message.

Comment: FYI this works fine out-of-the-box with [coursier](http://get-coursier.io) (tested with 1.0.0-RC12).

Comment: @al3xar Please post that as an answer.

Comment: Reading about coursier I had some hope it might work with sbt 1.3.3 (as sbt should be using coursier since 1.3.0), but I still get the same issue. How can one use coursier in a sbt project to avoid this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As a workaround you can set up a custom setting and provide the value for the Maven property as a JVM property:

```scala
lazy val mavenProps = settingKey[Unit]("workaround for Maven properties")
lazy val jcudaOs = settingKey[String]("")
lazy val jcudaArch = settingKey[String]("")
lazy val someProject = project
  .settings(
    scalaVersion := "2.12.3",
    libraryDependencies += "org.jcuda" % "jcuda" % "0.8.0",
    jcudaOs := "linux",
    jcudaArch := "x86_64",
    mavenProps := {
      sys.props("jcuda.os") = jcudaOs.value
      sys.props("jcuda.arch") = jcudaArch.value
      ()
    }
  )
```

This splits out the missing Maven properties as sbt setting, and then translates them into `sys.props` at the load time of the build.